# For the electric wire of a lamp, is the ribbed wire connected to the taller prong?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lamp

Does the ribbed wire get connected to the taller prong on the outlet?

Comment: I'd suggest an [edit] to include a photo, and it sounds like you're talking about U.S. plugs/outlets but confirming your locale would be nice.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the ribs indicate neutral, which is the tall blade on a standard
120v receptacle.

In the NEC the neutral is called the "grounded conductor", it is grounded at the transformer and the service. The Code recognizes the ribbed method for identifying this conductor in [NEC 400.22(F)](https://up.codes/viewer/colorado/nfpa-70-2023/chapter/4/equipment-for-general-use#400.22_(F)).